# Listening for button click and linking fragment with view model

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel

Im trying to learn view models and implement them in my app. I have been following a tutorial on getting me started but, I have a couple questions.

1. How do i listen for a button click? Since all the business logic is suppose to be stored in the view model would I put an OnClick listener there? Or would i put it with my `onChange` method in the activity that launches the fragment?
2. How to tell the fragment to use the view model?

Update was looking at this guys tutorial [Location of click event in MVVM architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768019/location-of-click-event-in-mvvm-architecture) . Isn't the whole point of mvvm to eliminate the need of interfaces?

Update 2: Found where you can use data binding to shove OnClick listener into button here: [Handle onClick event with Databinding and MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533689/handle-onclick-event-with-databinding-and-mvvm) and [Using DataBinding library for binding events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961901/using-databinding-library-for-binding-events)

Live data observe code from activity launching fragment

```
 //private BattleRhythmViewModel battleModel;
   battleModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BattleRhythmViewModel.class);

   battleModel.getEvents().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<Event>>() {
       @Override
       public void onChanged(@Nullable ArrayList<Event> events) {
        // Add newly created events to array/recycler view
           // Another one for pushing new platform/content to database


       }
   });
}
```

View model for fragment

public class BattleRhythmViewModel extends ViewModel  {

```
private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Event>> battleRhythmEvents;
private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<TableData>> battleRhythmExtra;

public LiveData<ArrayList<Event>> getEvents()
{
    return battleRhythmEvents;
}

public LiveData<ArrayList<TableData>> getExtras()
{
    return battleRhythmExtra;
}


}
```